# How can we configure scrapyd to use a virtualenv for a project?

Tags: python, virtualenv, scrapy

I am trying to configure a scrapyd to run on Ubuntu Server 12.04 machine. I am not able to deploy my projects to it because it can't find some libraries. I can install all the dependencies in the main or default python environment (the one maintained by the os) but I wouldn't want to do that.

Is there a way for `scrapyd` to be configured to use a python `virtualenv`? If yes, How? If no, why?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to install scrapyd using virtualenv on an Ubuntu Server. To install virtualenv, just type:

```
virtualenv environment_name
```

Then, you must activate the environment with:

```
source [PATH_TO_YOUR_ENVIRONMENT]/bin/activate
```

After that, you just have to install scrapyd:

```
pip install scrapyd
```

If any dependency is missing, just grab its name and install it with the same command:

```
pip install [DEPENDENCY_NAME]
```

After that, you should be able to run scrapyd with its command:

```
scrapyd
```